# in PHP, which Exception codes are mapped to http status codes?

Tags: php, exception, cakephp-3.0, http-status-codes

I'm developing a (CakePHP) web application, thereby creating own exception classes.

At the moment I try to create a locked exception, that shall return HTTP status code 423 (Locked):

```
<?php
namespace App\Exceptions;

use Cake\Network\Exception\HttpException;

class MeasuringPointLockedException extends HttpException{   
    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param string $message If no message is given 'Locked' will be the message
     */
    public function __construct($message = 'Locked'){   
        parent::__construct($message, 422);
    }
}    
?>
```

Unfortunately, at some point my code 423 is consumed and replaced by 500 (internal server error). I noticed, that only some codes are replaced, others (like 400, 404, 422) are passed through.

Note: HttpException is an extension of PHP builtin exception.

In between, I noticed, that response code 423 is intended for WebDAV services, but:

Is there any documentation, which codes are passed through? How could I achieve a status = 423 upon throwing (and not catching) such an exception?

Comment: All codes between 400 and 506, that are defined in `\Cake\Http\Response::$_statusCodes` can be set via HTTP exceptions, all other result in a 500 being set. I'd suggest that you enable debugging or check the logs to make sure there isn't a different error occouring than the one that you expect, also check **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/8962**. And please always mention your _exact_ CakePHP version (last line in `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: I'm Using Cake 3.3.1. Ok, I had a look into cakephp/cakephp/src/Network/Response.php and found the codes. Anyhow, is there a way to overcome this filter and pass other status codes via Exceptions? Thanks in advance ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can seen a bunch of http exceptions in here:
[https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/errors.html[1](https://book.cakephp.org/3/en/development/errors.html)

Here is also a good example of how to make this implementation:

```
use Cake\Core\Exception\Exception;

class MissingWidgetException extends Exception
{
    // Set your message here
    protected $_messageTemplate = 'Your message';

    // Set your status code here
    protected $_defaultCode = 404;
}

throw new MissingWidgetException(['widget' => 'Pointy']);
```